# ASP.NET C# Excel Exporter with multiple Excel Worksheets

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export

i have the Problem that i should Export a ASP:Table to Excel. The Export to Excel works fine, so here is my current code.

```
        string[] htmlTableString = generateHtmlTable(divs);
        StringBuilder sb_ExcelData = new StringBuilder();
        sb_ExcelData.Append(@"<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><title>KzB</title>");
        sb_ExcelData.Append(@"<body lang=EN-US style='mso-element:header' id=h1><span style='mso--code:DATE'></span><div class=Section1>");
        sb_ExcelData.Append("<DIV  style='font-size:12px;'>");
        sb_ExcelData.Append(htmlTableString[0]);  // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        sb_ExcelData.Append("</div></body></html>");
        string strFile = "Kzb_"+"Jahr_"+dd_Year.SelectedValue+ "_Export_" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xls";
        string strcontentType = "application/excel";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.ContentType = strcontentType;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFile);
        Response.Write(sb_ExcelData.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
```

In the Code you can see the string[] htmlTableString, there is my ASP:Table Content. Now i would like to Display for each contained string a new sheet/worksheet/tab in Excel. So how can i get this Feature?

I searched a lot, but i don't wanna use a external library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a possibility by using the informations from Glix @Glix
I use the EEPlus Lib to create multiple Worksheets.

For exmaple in a way like this:

```
private MemoryStream createMemoryStream(DataTable[] tables, int[] divs)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
            for (int i = 0; i < tables.Length; i++)
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Division_" + divs[i].ToString());
                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tables[i], true);
            }
            pck.SaveAs(ms);
            return ms;
        }
```

The MemoryStream could be used for a Response.BinaryWrite. In this way you could download the Excel File with different Tabs/Worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many different manual techniques for exporting Excel in ASP.NET.  I've found that by far the most efficient is creating the Excel files in the [Office XML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats).  This has the disadvantage of requiring the user to save it as a .xlsx file after they download it.  But the files are very light weight and download very quickly. Here is a good [step by step tutorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) on how the build an Office XML Excel file.

You can also use the newer [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) format.  This creates the file in the .xlsx format.  But it requires you to use the [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124).  Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97307/Using-C-and-Open-XML-SDK-for-Microsoft-Office) on using the Office Open XML SDK.

Comment: Ist there no possibility to get a solution with my current code? I cant believe that it doesnt work in a way like this

Comment: can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't with the code you are currently using. It's just a dirty hack of writing html to file, that excel can open because MS accept html in their office products.

As above, use XML format, or a 3rd party plugin like EPPlus.

Comment: is there no possibility to hack a solution for my Problem?

Comment: Can you give me a Solution?

Comment: I can't share my code. However I can point you at the old example which walks you through the code needed so you can create multiple sheets in a workbook with EPPlus (you can install with nuget): http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html